# Is it possible to create a new xml file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, http

I want to store html text box data periodically to restore it to save the time of retyping in the event of browser crash or submit failure, I can do it using html5 localstorage or javascript cookies but i want to access that data across from different browser and it must be a client side process, So can i create a xml or any file in client machine to save the input field data periodically and access it from all browser ??

Answer (score 2):

No.

Anywhere you can save it client side will be sandboxed (and thus accessible only to the browser that stored it).

The closest you could come would be to periodically synchronise the local store with a server.